# Android spinner, Why I can't select item on first position?

Tags: android, spinner

I created spinner in my app and I'm filling it with data from a database. It works ok until I want to select item in first position, when I do that spinner closes and nothing is hapennig.  But if I choose item on any other positions it works just fine and i don't have any idea why ?
my code:

```
public String returnString(AdapterView<?> parent,int position,long ID){
    return parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
}

void showDrugStores()
{    

    final DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
    db.open();
    final Cursor drugCursor;

    Spinner drugStoreSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.drugStoreSpinner);
    drugCursor = db.getDrugStores();
    drugCursor.moveToFirst();
    startManagingCursor(drugCursor);

    String[] from = new String[]{db.KEY_NAZWAAPTEKI}; 
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.tvDBViewRow};

    SimpleCursorAdapter drugStoreAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.closed_spinner, drugCursor, from, to);
    drugStoreAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.db_view_row);
    drugStoreSpinner.setAdapter(drugStoreAdapter);

    drugStoreSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
            View view, int pos, long id) {

            String selection = returnString(parent, pos, id);
            db.open();
            db.getDruSto(selection);

            TextView show_selected =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.show);
            show_selected.setText(drugCursor.getString(1));

            db.close();
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because the first item is ALREADY selected - if you want to add an option to represent that nothing is selected, you should add that to the head of your list.